# How to get frame rate and stream count information of video files into a text file with using MediaInfo?

Tags: windows, batch-file, mediainfo

I have a problem with a console command executed from within a batch file in a command prompt window on Windows 7. I want to get the frame rate and the number of audio streams of a video and write them into a text file. For the frame rate there is no problem, I run this command from a batch file:

```
for %%a in (C:\Documents) do (
    echo.
    Mediainfo --Inform=Video;%%FrameRate%% %%a
)>> "D:\TestFrame2.txt"
```

But for the number of audio streams, it returns an empty text and there is no error message. I use exactly the same batch file, but I replaced `Video` by `Audio` and `FrameRate` by `StreamCount`.

I see these parameters when I run `Mediainfo --Help-Inform`.

And also a lot of others options like `Mediainfo --Inform=General;%%AudioCount%%` don't work.

I have tested already to replace `Inform` by `Output` and there is no change. And I have tested also to use this command directly in the console window without redirecting the results into a text file and it's the same thing.

What is the reason for not getting number of audio streams written to the text file?

Comment: `for %%a in (C:\Documents) do  echo %%a` gives `C:\Documents` - and nothing more. Is that, what you want?

Comment: FYI: It's not Ms Dos, it's the Windows Command Prompt. MS-DOS was an operating system, and so is Windows 7.

Comment: Ho I'm really sorry I did an error in my message. For my command I don't use (C:\Documents) but (C:\Documents\*.mov).

Answer (score 2):

Use [MediaInfoCLI](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/Download/Windows) to redirect its output to a file, and there's no need to enumerate the files as the program can do it.

- List frame rates without file names:

  ```
  pushd c:\documents
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\MediaInfo\MediaInfoCLI" --output=Video;%%FrameRate%%\r\n ^
      *.mpg *.mp4 *.mkv *.avi *.m4a *.flac *.mp3 *.wav >"D:\TestFrame2.txt"
  popd
  ```
- List filenames and frame rates separated by `:` (note that as it fetches info from multiple MediaInfo sections a template file is required):

  ```
  pushd c:\documents
  (
      echo General;%%FileName%%%%FileExt%%:
      echo Video;%%FrameRate%%\r\n
  ) >"%temp%\mediainfotemplate"

  "C:\Program Files (x86)\MediaInfo\MediaInfoCLI" ^
      --output="file://%temp%\mediainfotemplate" ^
      *.mpg *.mp4 *.mkv *.avi *.m4a *.flac *.mp3 *.wav >"D:\TestFrame2.txt"

  del "%temp%\mediainfotemplate"
  popd
  ```

Instead of the explicit file type list you can use `*` to process all files.

Comment: Thanks for your respond but I have an error message "access denied". So I run the file as administrator but I have the same message. It's the same thing if I run the command directly from the command prompt as administrator.. It's weird because normally I have all rights.

Comment: @Babadi48, follow the standard procedure: remove/comment any `echo off` lines, execute the batch file from a Command Prompt console and check the command which produces the error.

Answer (score 0):

.
`C:\Documents` is a folder, you have to specify a mask like `*.*`, `*.txt`, `my-video-??.*` or `*.mp4` `*.avi`

Example for video AVI.

```
(for %%a in (C:\Documents\*.avi) do (echo fake-command %%a)
)>_TestFrame2.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for your respond, I already test that. In my first post I forgot to write    (C:\Documents\ ***.avi**). So it doesn't work. For the Frame Rate it's OK but with Audio StreamCount and a lot of others commands it return nothing without error message...